# js-ctypes: Pointer to intptr_t

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, jsctypes

In ctypes I have

```
TBButton.ptr(ctypes.UInt64("0x1e677e60")
```

This is equivalent to `aButton.address()` in this line of code here:

```
var rez = SendMessage(hToolbar, 0x417 /** TB_GETBUTTON **/, 1, aButton.address());
```

When I run this code i get error:

> Exception: expected type intptr_t, got TBButton.ptr(ctypes.UInt64("0xaa4eb20"))

So this is because in my `SendMessage` defintion I have this:

```
var SendMessage = user32.declare('SendMessageW', ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.intptr_t,
    ctypes.voidptr_t, // HWND
    ctypes.uint32_t, // MSG
    ctypes.uintptr_t, // WPARAM
    ctypes.intptr_t // LPARAM
);
```

So my question is: What is the type of `TBButton.ptr(ctypes.UInt64("0x1e677e60")` so I can change `LPARAM` in the `SendMessage` defintion to this type.

Or alternatively: Is it possible to make this a `intptr_t`?
Something like `ctypes.intptr_t(aButton.address())`, which I tried this it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pointer to `TBButton`, whatever `TBButton` is, while `intptr_t` is actually an integer large enough to hold a pointer address.

You need to cast the pointer to an `intptr_t`.

```
var lparam = ctypes.cast(tbbuttonptr, ctypes.intptr_t);
```

Comment: I tried this but i get error: `var aButton = ctypes.cast(new struct_TBButton(), ctypes.intptr_t);
var rez = SendMessage(hToolbar, 0x417 /** TB_GETBUTTON **/, 1, aButton.address());` error returned is = 
`Exception: expected type intptr_t, got ctypes.intptr_t.ptr(ctypes.UInt64("0x11d87c00"))`

Comment: if I then do `aButton.address()` it hangs up on drwatsn32.exe: `var aButton = ctypes.cast(new struct_TBButton(), ctypes.intptr_t);
var rez = SendMessage(hToolbar, 0x417 /** TB_GETBUTTON **/, 1, aButton);`

Comment: My code is here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/f691ab9a750f24be346f (its on winxp) please help ive been struggling with it for long time :(

Comment: Tried it and it did the crash/hang on drwatsn32.exe :( `var aButton = new struct_TBButton();
var rez = SendMessage(hToolbar, 0x417 /** TB_GETBUTTON **/, 1, ctypes.cast(aButton.address(), ctypes.intptr_t));` the value of rez after i kill drwatsn32.exe process is 0

Comment: That is unrelated to the question, which was about how to cast something. You asked your "crash" question a couple of times already in other contexts... You should probably wait for somebody to answer it instead of *spamming* the same thing to various comment sections...

Comment: Oh ok forgive me please I worked on it and thought it was hanging because I was doing wrong type. In the other places I was just thinking that all that context was the issue for the hang. Ill stop.

Comment: You got your answer now over at ask.moz

Comment: No way thanks man Ill go check it out! Edit: Oh my gosh it was you, thank you man. :'(